# Updating attribute of a TR in jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

Im trying to modify the column values of a row and the row attributes after the Datatable initialised. I was able to modify the row data without any trouble using this code. I'm using the row ID to select a specific row. Here the code Im using for updating the second column value of that specific row.

```
var row = oTable.row("#tr_" + QuestionID.toString()).data();
row[1] = NewData;
oTable.row("#tr_" + QuestionID.toString()).data(row);
```

Once this code is executed the content of the second column being replaced by the newData. This part is working fine.

But I've an attribute for every **TR** which is **questiontype**. So I need to update that attribute also.

So I added the code

```
$(row).attr('questiontype', NewQuestionType);
```

But this doesnt makes anything for that specific row even when the data change is working fine.

So how can I change the attribute value of that row

Comment: `row` returns data not an element so `$(row)` is really `$(rowData)`. Suggest you look at how the row render callbacks work and do it there

Comment: If you want change the attr of tr element use `$("#tr_" + QuestionID.toString()).attr('questiontype', NewQuestionType)`, its working=??

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this issue which am sharing for those having the same issue.

Just use nodes

```
**oTable.row("#tr_" + QuestionID.toString()).nodes().to$().attr("questiontype", QuestionType);**
```